# How to set IP config to network adapter in Universal windows app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I am naive in Windows 10 Universal Windows app. I need to assign IP address to the Ethernet card, programatically. I am able to achieve it in normal .net app, but in UWP app, I am struggling with it. Kindly help.

Any resource or link will be a good help. Thanks in Advance

I am using Vs 2015, Windows 10

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you achieving it in the normal .net app? Might be easier to work from there than us start from scratch.

Comment: @jaymee in normal .net you have process class, and you can call cmd/bat files to do so. or you can use Pinvoke to use low level windows api to do so.

Answer (score 0):

this cannot be done from UWP apps at this moment. Because there are no apis exposed to do this.

Why do you want to do this from an app btw? Windows has enough features itself to do this so I don't see the need of an app setting or changing my IP address.

Is this part of an Windows-10 IOT? Because then it might be possible by calling a powershell command:

How to add powershell to IOT app:
http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PowerShell.htm

How to change IP address using powershell:
http://www.howtogeek.com/112660/how-to-change-your-ip-address-using-powershell/